# Validate a form without submitting

Tags: javascript, string, forms, validation, comparison

I have the following code that checks to see that two select fields are identical. The code works alright when called with onsubmit. However after doing this validation the form is still submitted. How can i prevent the script or my form from submitting the incorrect data.

Please see code below:

```
var fieldalias="Email address field"

function verify(element1, element2) {
    var passed=false
    if (element1.value=='') {
        alert("Please fill out the "+fieldalias+"!")
        element1.focus()
    }
    else if (element2.value=='') {
        alert("Please verify the "+fieldalias+"!")
        element2.focus()
    }
    else if (element1.value!=element2.value) {
        alert("The two "+fieldalias+"s do not match")
        element1.select()
    }
    else
        passed=true

    return passed

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Answer (score 0):

Call that code with different event, like i.e: onchange, or onfocusout. This way the validation will be performed every time user enter some values to your fields, certainly before submitting.

EDIT:

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but I would have attached your JS code this way:

First assign your select box to the variable:

```
var object_input = document.getElementById("selectId");
```

And then:

```
if(object_input.addEventListener)
{
    object_input.addEventListener('blur', focus_lost);  
    object_input.addEventListener('keypress', checkForEnter);
}
else
{
    object_input.attachEvent('onblur', focus_lost);  
    object_input.attachEvent('onkeypress', checkForEnter);
}
```

and then perform your validation ith focus_lost or checkForEnter.

Comment: can i use this select boxes cos its not working, i tried it with select boxes and they work alright but not preventing the submission so the forms submits anyway with incorrect data

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include your HTML, so I'm going to assume you've added onsubmit() to your form element.

If so, make sure your call looks like this:

```
onsubmit="return verify(element1, element2)"
```

(replace element1 and element2 accordingly)

If this assumption is not correct, please include some additional detail so we can better assist.

Comment: onSubmit="return verify(this.sel, this.sel2)"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in the html code you have something like this:

```
<form action="test2.html" method="post" onsubmit="return verify(e1, e2);">
    <input type="text" name="e1" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="e2" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
</form>
```

You have to put in onsubmit event:

```
return verify(e1, e2);
```

so you will not go to the submiting page if the data is not valida

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is the

```
element1.select()
```

in the 3rd if, that this select method does not exist for a select object.

You can use a

```
element1.focus()
```

The code that will work is:

```
var fieldalias="Email address field"

        function verify(element1, element2){
            var passed=false;
            if (element1.value==''){
                alert("Please fill out the "+fieldalias+"!");
                element1.focus();
            }
            else if (element2.value==''){
                alert("Please verify the "+fieldalias+"!");
                element2.focus();
            }
            else if (element1.value!=element2.value){
                alert("The two "+fieldalias+"s do not match");
                element1.focus();
            }
            else
                passed=true;

            return passed;

        }
```

And

```
<form action="test2.html" method="post" onsubmit="return verify(document.getElementById('e1'), document.getElementById('e2'));">
    <select id="e1">
      <option value="One">One</option>
      <option value="two">two</option>
      <option value="Three">Three</option>
      <option value="four">four</option>
    </select><br/>
    <select id="e2">
      <option value="One">One</option>
      <option value="two">two</option>
      <option value="Three">Three</option>
      <option value="four">four</option>
    </select><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling stopImmediatePropagation() on the event to prevent any further processing of the submit event by any other handlers in the form element or higher level elements.

Comment: Interesting Micrus... how do i add this?